# Providing and Requiring Emacs Lisp Package Sub-features (How to)

Tags: emacs, package, elisp

I have been writing Emacs Lisp packages for a while.  However, I have yet to find/encounter a SINGLE example using require and provide with sub-features.  Honestly, the explanation given in the Emacs Lisp manual is absolutely laughable.  It tells you why you would want to use sub-features but does not show how to use them.  It does not even tell you if the sub-feature parameters in require and provide should be symbols for files in the path or filenames.  Hence, my question...

Could somebody provide a dead-simple example of how sub-features work? 
Specifically:

1. Can you give me simple example of a package providing one feature and two sub-features?
2. Can you give me an example requiring the above feature and only one of the two sub-features provided by the package in 1

Thanks much in advance,

Pablo

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I didn't even know subfeatures were a thing until I read this question.

Subfeatures seem to be for complex features that may have some capabilities on one platform (e.g. Linux) but not on another (e.g. Windows), or some similar situation.  Users of the feature can test for a subfeature and do workarounds if it's not there.

As for using subfeatures, you just add a list argument like `(provide 'foo '(bar baz))`, but more likely with some programmatically generated list like

```
(setq foo--subfeatures ())
(when (barp) 
  (setq foo--subfeatures (cons 'bar foo--subfeatures))) 
(provide 'foo foo--subfeatures)
```

Then test with `(featurep 'foo 'bar)` to make sure `foo` has the `bar` subfeature.  The subfeatures are just symbols.  A built in example of a feature with subfeatures is `make-network-process`, which is implemented in C but the subfeature mechanism should be pretty clear even if you're unfamiliar with C.  Another example in lisp is a `provide` in `files.el` and a corresponding `featurep` in `tramp-compat.el`.

It doesn't look like `require` cares at all about subfeatures; its job is to load a feature if it's not loaded, and a feature is loaded with all subfeatures.  Subfeatures are implemented as a list in the `subfeatures` property of the feature symbol, e.g. `(get 'foo 'subfeatures) -> (bar baz)`.  It looks like `provide` overwrites the property, so only the last call to `provide` is relevant.

Comment: I appreciate the effort.  This much I understood from the Emacs manual.  However, it is still unclear to me how to write and use sub-features. I do get why they sub-features are needed.  What I don't get is how to write and use them. I suspect (but have not tried) that a package that is divided into multiple files, could have a "master" file that includes provide states for the other "smaller" files.  This way, one could use the part of a complex, multi-file package that one needs without loading the entire package.  I will report back if this actually works.  Again, this is only a suspicion.

Comment: But I said how to write and use them.  You give an extra list to `provide` and use `featurep` with an extra arg to test for them.  `require` doesn't care about subfeatures, so you're going to load the whole feature whether it has subfeatures or not.  Use separate features to load separate parts of a package.  Subfeatures indicate some sort of functionality that may or may not be present in a feature.

Comment: I found an example in lisp, and I've updated the answer.

Comment: So you don't `require` sub-features at all; but after requiring the (entire) feature, you can test at run-time whether or not a given sub-feature was provided.